# Determining whether or not the given maps are linear transformations from $C[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working through some homework problems right now, and I'm a little confused. Here is the question that I am stuck on.

> Determine whether the following maps are linear transformations from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> a) $T_{1}(f) = f(0)$
>
> b) $T_{2}(f) = |f(0)|$
>
> c) $T_{3}(f) = \frac{1}{2}(f(0) + f(1))$
>
> d) $T_{4}(f) = \left[\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^{2} d x\right]^{2}$

It should be noted that $C[0,1]$ is the set of all continuous real-valued functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$, and that $f \in C[0,1]$.

So I know that to prove whether or not something is a linear transformation the following two properties need to hold.

1. $T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v), \forall u, v \in V$
2. $T(\lambda u) = \lambda (T(u)), \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{F} \text{  and  } \forall u \in V$

I understand that each $T$ is just a map of some map in the set $C[0,1]$, but what I don't understand is what exactly $f(0), f(1)$, and $f(x)$ denote in the context of this question? I guess I'm more so looking for clarification as to what exactly is being asked in the above question.

Comment: $f$ is an element of a vector space $C[0,1],$ elements of which can be added and multiplied by scalars; question (a) is whether the map that takes $f \in C[0,1]$ to $f(0)$ is a linear transformation (loosely speaking, is compatible with addition and scalar multiplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maps are maps from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Their input is a whole function $f$ in $C[0,1]$ and their output is a real number somehow related to the given function (its value at some point, its integral, etc.) Suppose you want to show property (1) for your first map. You would do
$$
T(f+g)=(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=T(f)+T(g)
$$
the first equality being true by definition of $T$ the second by definition of $f+g$ and the third again by definition of $T$